# Why Suddenly Laravel started showing 'page not found' error?

Tags: php, laravel

I was working on my project and suddenly Laravel started showing `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` error. Here is how my **web.php**, **CarController.php** and **view's location** looks like.

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
    Route::get('cars/create',"CarController@create");
}
```

**CarController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Car;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Auth;

class CarController extends Controller
{
     public function create()
     {
         return view('cars.create');
     }
}
```

**View cars.create** exist at **/resources/views/cars/create.blade.php**.

I don't know what caused this error but It's really irritating. I think this error came into existence because I had created one model named `Request` which might conflict with the actual `Request` class made by Laravel.

But, As soon as I saw the error, I deleted that Model including migration and controller. But still, the error is there. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan clear-compiled`?

Comment: are you using a linux distro? maybe it's a file permission problem

Comment: Yes, I am on `ubunut 16.04`.

Comment: plz set `APP_DEBUG` to true and then  refresh the page and tell me the error

Comment: @JulioPérez, Permissions is not an issue!

Comment: @MahdiYounesi, `APP-DEBUG` is already on. It's just showing `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`.

Comment: is this error persist only for this specific url?

Comment: @Sohel0415 Yes brother!

Comment: Can you give us the url you are trying to access to?

Comment: what's the url you are trying to access??

Comment: @NikolaGavric, it's `http://localhost:8000/cars/create`

Comment: type out this command in your console and include the image inside of your question: `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @NikolaGavric, here we go! it's there! https://pastebin.com/H3aTEAew

Comment: add your full route

Comment: Other routes are working, except only this one? @Ciarán

Comment: @NikolaGavric, Yes! Only this one is not working!

Comment: run `php artisan route:clear` , `php artisan view:clear` , `php:artisan cache:clear`

Comment: when I change my route to `car/create` from `cars/create`, it works!

Comment: can you show us your full `web.php` file so I can answer why the route didn't work, I think I know why, but wanna see your full file first

Comment: Here we go -> https://pastebin.com/77TrB3Ci

Comment: @Ciarán your route definition is in wrong order, see my answer, it should solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::get('cars',"CarController@index");
Route::get('cars/{car}',"CarController@show");///remove this route definition or keep it at the end of your route file
```

Comment: Woow! How can I miss that!

Comment: we all do such mistakes, that's why we share our views with each others :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in ?? when you're trying to get the route??
usually what happens is the session expires after sometime.